# Dell Latitude E6230 WWAN / 1/2 Mini slots

Tags: ssd, msata, wwan

I have a Dell Latitude E6230 with Intel Core i7, 16 GB RAM, 480 GB Sandisk SSD and recently I found that it has two small slots inside, one named WWAN and the other 1 / 2 MINI. I googled about this and the opinions are different. My question is, can I run an mSATA SSD into one of this slots?

I just bought an Samsung 860 EVO mSATA 500 GB and I’ve seen on some forums that people are running these in the WWAN slot on different laptops.

Is there an additional setting to do in BIOS or something to make it run?

Thanks!

Comment: The WWAN slot is probably wired specifically for WWAN and won't work for anything else. I have a Latitude E5450 and people have tried to run misc. stuff from this slot (SSDs, eGPUs) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Dell models have a WWAN socket that can accept mSata, but these usually also
have "mSata" written near to the "WWAN".

The 1/2 MINI card was intended for the Dell encryption module.
Dell offered that as a way to encrypt your hard drive, instead of having the CPU
do the job. SSDs were not in grand use at the time and the slot cannot be used for it.

I'm afraid that these sockets are not useful for that purpose.